# Image not shown using Qpixmap with QT5.4 and mvs2013 x64

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit, qpixmap, qlabel

I am using QT (version 5.4 msvc2013_64) with of-course vs2013. The compilation is successful but when running not every thing functions. Before with vs2010 and QT (i think version 5.1 msvc_2010_opengl do not remember exactly) every thing was working but now things are wried which maybe typical with the start of newer versions but need to be resolved. I also got other issues with this but lets get this resolved first as maybe others will be resolved too else I will post another question for the other problems. Of-course If i do not see a solution to this problem with the current QT and vs I will switch to vs2012 (requires downloading and installing); Maybe then everything will work as before. Thanks in advance.

ui_ta7feezquran.h

```
/********************************************************************************
    ** Form generated from reading UI file 'ta7feezquran.ui'
    **
    ** Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.4.1
    **
    ** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
    ********************************************************************************/

#ifndef UI_TA7FEEZQURAN_H
#define UI_TA7FEEZQURAN_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QAction>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtWidgets/QHeaderView>
#include <QtWidgets/QLabel>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QToolBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_Ta7feezQuranClass
{
public:
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QLabel *a;
    QMenuBar *menuBar;
    QToolBar *mainToolBar;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *Ta7feezQuranClass)
    {
        if (Ta7feezQuranClass->objectName().isEmpty())
            Ta7feezQuranClass->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("Ta7feezQuranClass"));
        Ta7feezQuranClass->resize(572, 485);
        centralWidget = new QWidget(Ta7feezQuranClass);
        centralWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("centralWidget"));
        a = new QLabel(centralWidget);
        a->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("a"));
        a->setGeometry(QRect(-30, -20, 601, 471));
        a->setPixmap(QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8(":/Ta7feezQuran/Resources/Amasjed Alharam.jpg")));
        a->setScaledContents(true);
        Ta7feezQuranClass->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
        menuBar = new QMenuBar(Ta7feezQuranClass);
        menuBar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("menuBar"));
        menuBar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 572, 21));
        menuBar->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
        Ta7feezQuranClass->setMenuBar(menuBar);
        mainToolBar = new QToolBar(Ta7feezQuranClass);
        mainToolBar->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("mainToolBar"));
        Ta7feezQuranClass->addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, mainToolBar);

        retranslateUi(Ta7feezQuranClass);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(Ta7feezQuranClass);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *Ta7feezQuranClass)
    {
        Ta7feezQuranClass->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("Ta7feezQuranClass", "Ta7feezQuran", 0));
        a->setText(QString());
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class Ta7feezQuranClass: public Ui_Ta7feezQuranClass {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_TA7FEEZQURAN_H
```

ta7feezquran.h

```
#ifndef TA7FEEZQURAN_H
#define TA7FEEZQURAN_H

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_ta7feezquran.h"

class Ta7feezQuran : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Ta7feezQuran(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Ta7feezQuran();

private:
    Ui::Ta7feezQuranClass ui;
};

#endif // TA7FEEZQURAN_H
```

ta7feezquran.cpp

```
#include "ta7feezquran.h"

Ta7feezQuran::Ta7feezQuran(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

Ta7feezQuran::~Ta7feezQuran()
{

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "ta7feezquran.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Ta7feezQuran w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

ta7feezquran.qrc

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/Ta7feezQuran">
        <file>Resources/Amasjed Alharam.jpg</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: Check that the image is actually JPG format and that you have qjpeg plugin installed.

Comment: The image is an actual JPG image and qjpeg plugin is installed. Maybe the qjpeg.dll should referenced in vs? If yes how to reference it or make sure it is included?

Comment: It should be loaded dynamically at run time. When deploying, by default Qt plugins should be placed in `imageformats` directory, next to the executable. So you need to have `imageformats\qjpeg.dll`.

Comment: so the executable that I want to run should have  imageformats\qjpeg.dll next to it? I will try that and post the results

Comment: every thing else worked when I placed the other needed Qt plugins next to the executable. Thanks alot. Should I place this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Application features used, for example images, multimedia, print support, etc., require the use of qt plugins.

The required plugins should be copied to the executable folder (folder where .exe file is included) by copying the plugin folders (with the dlls included) and pasting them inside the executable folder. Every thing else should work as expected.

In this case imageformats folder (with qjpeg.dll included as the file used is jpg) is needed to copied.